# Voice/Speech Recognition on windows platform

Tags: windows

Is there a way to use the voice recognition platform provided by microsoft to build an app which uses the voice to perform some tasks?

Comment: Do you really want to know **if** it's possible, or do you want to know **how** to do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361572%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what it's designed for. Here is some documentation with examples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh378426%28v=office.14%29.aspx